# Has there been any progress on this open problem about co-well-poweredness of accessible categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, large-cardinals, open-problems, accessible-categories

On the relations between accessible categories and large cardinal axioms, one big example is the following:

> Assume the existence of a proper class of strongly compact cardinals. Then every accessible category is co-well-copowered.

This can be found, for instance, in the standard reference **Makkai-Paré** (*Acessible categories: The Foundations of Categorical Model Theory*). We have

> Proposition 6.2.2: If pushouts are detectable in $\mathcal{K}$ (that is, the category of diagrams which have pushouts is accessible), $\mathcal{K}$ is co-well-powered

This also follows imitating the argument in Theorem 2.49 of **Adamek-Rosicky** (*Locally presentable and accessible categories*).

The important result is:

> Theorem 6.3.8 (M-P): Assume there is a proper class of strongly compact cardinals. Then colimits are uniformly detectable in every accessible category, that is, the subcategory of $\mathrm{Diag}(A)$ (the total category) whose objects are diagrams admiting colimits is accessible.

From there we can deduce detectability of pushouts and the result follows. Furthermore, every accessible category being co-wellpowered implies the existence of a proper class of measurable cardinals, as Example A.19 of *Locally presentable and accessible categories* shows with a counterexample using transitive models of ZC and a formal initial object, assuming there's a maximal measurable cardinal. There's probably an example in Makkai-Paré too but I don't recall any.

Thus the large cardinal strength of the assertion "every accesible category is co-well-powered" lies somewhere between "there's a proper class of strongly compacts" and "there's a proper class of measurables", but as far as I know this is an open problem, and even though I by no means have made an exhaustive research on its status, I did some for my bachelor thesis (on the topic of accessible categories, AECs and large cardinals), and haven't been able to find anything at all (except for an article of Bagaria using supercompacts).

Has there been any development on this open problem? What is the most likely direction: an argument assuming a proper class of measurables or deriving a proper class of strongly compacts?

Comment: You say "a class of" several times, but I think you probably mean "a proper class of", since every set including the empty set is also a class, and so there is always a class of compact cardinals, even if there are none. Also, you refer to compact cardinals, but in large cardinal set theory we usually refer either to weakly compact or to strongly compact cardinals (and these have vastly different consistency strengths). Historically, "compact" was often used for strongly compact, but this is now uncommon, and I'm not entirely sure which notion is meant here. So it may be good to clarify.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Indeed, despite putting some details I lazily abbreviated on other parts. I'll edit.

Comment: The Makkai-Paré result 6.3.8 is for diagrams of an arbitrary small shape $A$, I take it. In this case, we only need a particular $A$ -- the diagram shape $\bullet \leftarrow \bullet \to \bullet$ for pushouts. Maybe you don't actually need a proper class of strongly compacts to run their argument in this case?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, it does seem like uniform detectability is too strong of a result to be needed. I haven't checked the details but wanted to do later if the argument on Makkai-Paré runs (or could run) with just compactness (that js, assuming a proper class of $L_{\kappa, \omega}$-compacts), as is the case of the other known result relating accessible categories and large cardinals (powerful images).

Comment: From the other end, there's probably little reason to think the lower bound of a proper class of measurables is sharp -- in Adamek and Rosicky, the same lower bound was given for the consistency strength of Vopenka's principle, which is of course actually much stronger.

Comment: In the historical remarks to the chapter, Adamek and Rosicky attribute Example A.19 to Makkai and Pare, as well as to Mekler. A little digging reveals it's Prop 3.4.5 in Makkai and Pare -- and it's explained in a bit more detail there (although they assume _no_ measurable cardinals).

Comment: @TimCampion Seems to me there's a weird but somewhat simple direct argument using the existence of $L_{\kappa, \omega}$-compacts. The ideia is to show the subcat of $Q/\mathcal{K}$ of arrows not epi form an accessible category, so they are axiomatizable by a (basic) sentence and so their "complement" is too, and under the same cardinal hypothesis this implies preaccessibility thus boundedness. It sounds a bit too simple to be true, but I'd appreciate if someone else could go throught it. [Here's the argument](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LunqnUVEaDW_pKN6xsl1KC92FrO64W3_/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @TimCampion Sorry to keep tagging you, but just in case I updated with some details on the axiomatization because it was very vague and slightly incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from your note -- the idea that the complement of an accessible subcategory is still preaccessible is particularly interesting! However, in the last paragraph you are essentially claiming that a $\lambda$-pure subobject of a non-epimorphism is again a non-epimorphism, which I don't think is true. I think the error lies in the last diagram -- for your argument you need to know that the lower triangle commutes but purity only gives that the upper triangle commutes. (BTW I think it's not necessary to prove purity in $K$ -- what you really use is purity in $C/K$ anyway!)

Comment: @TimCampion You're right, I forgot this basic fact which was conveniently used to show something that sounds way too strong (subobjects of non-epis). Thanks for reading anyway! I'm still thinking if it can be weakened to something like the full image (in which case we'd have only preaccessbility), I'll update in case I stumble upon anything interesting.

Comment: @TimCampion I've written another suspiciously simpler argument, if you wanna check it out.

Comment: Looks good to me! That’s a nice argument!